# ArcGIS InfoTemplate setTitle setContent is not a function

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using ArcGIS JS API 3.24 and I got an error saying that

```
Uncaught TypeError: cellInfoTemplate.setTitle is not a function
```

But I'm sure that I have already included `esri/InfoTemplate` in my `require`. 
Here is more:

```
 require([
  "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/InfoTemplate",
  "esri/tasks/GeometryService", "esri/layers/ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer",
  "esri/layers/TableDataSource", "esri/layers/QueryDataSource", "esri/layers/LayerDataSource", "esri/layers/DynamicLayerInfo",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/renderers/SimpleRenderer", "esri/layers/LayerDrawingOptions",
  "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/renderers/UniqueValueRenderer",
  "esri/config",
  "esri/Color", "dojo/domReady!"
], function (
  Map, Layers, FeatureLayer, InfoTemplate,
  GeometryService, ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer,
  TableDataSource, QueryDataSource, LayerDataSource, DynamicLayerInfo,
  SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleRenderer, LayerDrawingOptions,
  PictureMarkerSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, SimpleMarkerSymbol, UniqueValueRenderer,
  esriConfig,
  Color
) { 
    var cellInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate();
    cellInfoTemplate.setTitle("Details");
    cellInfoTemplate.setContent(getCellHTML());

    var featureLayer = new esri.layers.FeatureLayer("myUrl", {
        "opacity": 0.6,
    });

    featureLayer.setInfoTemplates(infoTempDict);

    function getCellHTML(){ ... }
    ... other codes ...
 }
```

And if I avoid using `.setTitle` and `.setContent` with

```
var cellInfoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("Details",getCellHTML());
```

It will return me

```
Uncaught TypeError: featureLayer.setInfoTemplates is not a function
```

So can anyone tell me how to solve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, after some testing, I got a little change to let my codes work:

The function `.setInfoTemplates( {layers: InfoTemplates} )` should work on a `dynamicLayer`. For a single `featureLayer`, I need to use

```
featureLayer.setInfoTemplate(InfoTemplate)
```

In this way, no error in console and info window will jump out correctly.